# IIS App recycling vs manual browser cache delete

Tags: iis, caching, browser-cache

We have an .NET app. After deployment, we noticed that a number of users had to clear their cache in order for the page to work properly.

I was wondering if an IIS app recycling would do the same thing so the users do not need to clear their local cache.

Answer (score 0):

The server provides caching hints to the client in the response to each resource--many websites have different responses depending on the resource type (static files like .js libraries, css and images, versus dynamic results from .asp pages or API calls).  You can use Postman or Fiddler or the developer tools in your browser to view the response headers...and then you can control expiration either in the web.config, the global.asax or your individual code file.

For more information see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache
- [https://thedeveloperblog.com/expiration#:~:text=Expiration%20is%20key%20to%20caching%20in%20ASP.NET.%20We,performance%2C%20resulting%20in%20pages%20being%20expired%20much%20sooner](https://thedeveloperblog.com/expiration#:%7E:text=Expiration%20is%20key%20to%20caching%20in%20ASP.NET.%20We,performance%2C%20resulting%20in%20pages%20being%20expired%20much%20sooner).